# Create go-to CW questions for recurring topics on SU?

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

There are certain questions that keep appearing on Super User.

Should we create a few standard CW questions to point to when closing?

Here are a few topics that could use some standard guides, feel free to add to this list.

1. [How to deal with a virus/malware infested computer](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)
2. List of free tools for point 1
3. [What linux distro is suitable for ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45439/what-to-do-with-which-linux-distro-for-my-old-pc-questions-of-super-user)
4. Best backup/restore tools

   If you agree please answer with links to questions that you think might be suitable or if you'd like to create such a question.

Comment: How many is recurring?

Comment: @random - more than a few http://superuser.com/search?q=malware+virus

Comment: It seems like #3 would be a good candidate for a wiki, but shouldn't the others just link to the original?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Good idea indeed](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/faq), as long as we limit that for only a few topics which are **really** recurring.

We don't want to turn any frequent topic into such thing, though. The purpose of Super User is to provide feedback to individual questions, not to be a farm of "how to" questions. There are sites dedicated to such goal, like the [how-to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/).

Such questions should be references of common steps to follow, but not the ultimate answer to all these questions. The purpose of such "faq" would be to post as a comment, as an initial read for the poster, and suggest him to update his question with any specific and additional details.

Comment: pretty much my thoughts exactly.